# how can i change shortcuts of the node wrangler

Tags: node-editor

I'm looking to change the shortcut of "pulling out" a node from the node tree that's by default is alt+mouse drag to ctrl+mouse drag. The reason is I'm using alt+mouse drag to move around in the node view (pan). Is it possible somehow?

Comment: Just to make sure: You would like to change the shortcut to detach a node? If so, it's a regular Blender hotkey. Do a search for 'detach' in the preferences and set it to `Alt` instead (operator is `move_detach_links`), works for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSOvk.png

Answer (score 2):

If you know the shortcut but you don't know the name of the command, the way to search for a shortcut is to

- Edit preferences
- Select Keymap
- Set the search mode to *Key-Binding*
- Enter the key sequence for the shortcut.
- Scroll through the resulting list to find the relevant editor or modal

There is one Blender specific bit that you need to know.  In the Keymap, if you are looking for 'mouse drag' as part of the sequence you are looking for `tweak`.  The Blender manual on [Keymap](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/keymap.html) describes `tweak` as

> **Tweak**
>
> Mouse click and drag (optionally map drag direction to different actions).

So your search will look like

[image: Preferences in the Keymap tab showing how to search for a left mouse drag]

There are a lot of things that use that key-binding, but you're looking for the *Node Editor*, so click in the search results and scroll down until you find its section:

[image: search results scrolled to the Node Editor section]

There are a lot of possibilities, so you have to think about what the operation might be named.  In this case, as mentioned in the comments, `Detach` is the right choice.  If you click the arrow to expand the `Detach Entry` it looks like this:

[image: Detach entry expanded showing Alt modifier is selected]

Now that you've found the relevant entry the rest of the instructions are simple:

- Select the `Ctrl` button.
- If you don't have Auto Save set in preferences, then go to the lower right and click `Save Preferences`.